IB_INSYNC API timeout
When I try to connect to the TWS API using
util.logToConsole('DEBUG')
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7456, clientId=1)

every other time I get below error and it's so frustrating -
2024-11-11 20:46:46,809 ib_insync.client INFO Connecting to 127.0.0.1:7456 with clientId 1...
2024-11-11 20:46:46,812 ib_insync.client INFO Connected
2024-11-11 20:46:46,926 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 176,20241111 20:47:45 EST
2024-11-11 20:46:46,927 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 71,2,1,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,928 ib_insync.client INFO Logged on to server version 176
2024-11-11 20:46:46,946 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 9,1,4649
2024-11-11 20:46:46,958 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 15,1,U11493298,U14665191,U14703433,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,959 ib_insync.client INFO API connection ready
2024-11-11 20:46:46,960 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 61,1
2024-11-11 20:46:46,961 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 5,1
2024-11-11 20:46:46,962 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 99,0
2024-11-11 20:46:46,963 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 76,1,4649,U11493298,,0
2024-11-11 20:46:46,964 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 76,1,4650,U14665191,,0
2024-11-11 20:46:46,966 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 76,1,4651,U14703433,,0
2024-11-11 20:46:46,972 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 4,2,-1,2104,Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,973 ib_insync.wrapper INFO Warning 2104, reqId -1: Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
2024-11-11 20:46:46,974 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 4,2,-1,2104,Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,975 ib_insync.wrapper INFO Warning 2104, reqId -1: Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
2024-11-11 20:46:46,977 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 4,2,-1,2104,Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,977 ib_insync.wrapper INFO Warning 2104, reqId -1: Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
2024-11-11 20:46:46,978 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 4,2,-1,2104,Market data farm connection is OK:cafarm,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,979 ib_insync.wrapper INFO Warning 2104, reqId -1: Market data farm connection is OK:cafarm
2024-11-11 20:46:46,980 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 4,2,-1,2104,Market data farm connection is OK:usopt,
2024-11-11 20:46:46,981 ib_insync.wrapper INFO Warning 2104, reqId -1: Market data farm connection is OK:usopt
2024-11-11 20:46:46,983 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 4,2,-1,2104,Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm,
...
2024-11-11 20:46:47,747 ib_insync.client DEBUG <<< 74,1,4651
2024-11-11 20:46:47,749 ib_insync.client DEBUG >>> 7,3,4652,0,,,,,,
2024-11-11 20:46:51,759 ib_insync.ib INFO Disconnecting from 127.0.0.1:7456, 157 B sent in 9 messages, 26.7 kB received in 449 messages, session time 4.95 s.
2024-11-11 20:46:51,760 ib_insync.client INFO Disconnecting

I see many posts related to it everywhere but no solution. Do any of you found a workaround or is there any robust way to connect to TWS API and maintain persistency in the connection.

I'm not familar with this particular API, but it seems likely your id is wrong and should represent your account's ID
